# In which way I can write down for-loop with List in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, refactoring

Is it possible to use Lambda expression or better way to write down the for-loop?

```
public TaskDTO convertToDTO(Task task) {
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getPrecedingTasks().size(); i++)
        this.precedingTasks.add(task.getPrecedingTasks().get(i).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good as:

> task.getPrecedingTasks().stream().map(Task::getName).forEach(this.precedingTasks::add);

But since you are just retrieving the part of the `Task`, `map` and then `collect` as a list as:

```
this.precedingTasks = task.getPrecedingTasks().stream().map(Task::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Isn't it more straightforward and easier to understand? Since `stream` here is to do the mapping/converting and then collecting.

And also in this way, you don't need to do the initialisation for the `this.precedingTasks` as

```
this.precedingTasks = new ArrayList<>(); // to ensure it's not null;
```

Anyway, just personal preference here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete example, where I put System.out.println ... you should use a this.precedingTasks.addAll( ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Task t1 = new Task("myTask", Arrays.asList(new Task("innerTask1"), new Task("innerTask2")));
        System.out.println(t1.precedingTasks.stream().map(Task::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }

    static class Task {

        private String name;
        private List<Task> precedingTasks = new ArrayList<>();

        public Task(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Task(String name, List<Task> precedingTasks) {
            this.name = name;
            this.precedingTasks = precedingTasks;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public List<Task> getPrecedingTasks() {
            return precedingTasks;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
[innerTask1, innerTask2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct solution in my case:

```
task.getPrecedingTasks().stream().map(Task::getName).forEach(this.precedingTasks::add);
```

Thanks, for tips : )

Comment: ...after the changing from method to constructor of DTO

Comment: Although this works, I believe is better to use addAll like the example I sent you instead of adding the items individually into the collection as you are doing, like if you have 1000 tasks inside the Task object, why invoking add 1000 times instead of 1 time addAll, (which is by the way more efficient since it's doing an array copy), but as I said, it works anyway.